# Why these two jqueryUI callbacks behave differently?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, callback

I'm using callbacks in jqueryUI to ensure that the next animation will start at the end of the previous one. I'm trying to understand the reason why these two very similar callbacks lead to different results

These are the two different syntaxes:

```
//First callback
$(".main-container").switchClass("col", "col-9", addElements());

//Second Callback
$(".main-container").switchClass("col", "col-9", function(){
    addElements();
});
```

I'm using bootstrap, therefore the col to col-9 class switch. In the first callback the elements appended to the `main-container` are appended and shown while the animation is going, while in the second callback they appear after the `col` has expanded to `col-9`.

Why the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You explained the difference yourself. The first one is defining a function to be called once the operation is done - that is, a col is changed to a col9. It will will be called after one col is changed to a col9 and add an element.

The second one is defined using an anonymous function and because of that it will only be called after switchClass has been called for all single col in main container, adding the elements.

They may look the same - that is, a callback that calls addElements(), but in reality as you noticed yourself, they aren't. In the first, you are calling the function addElements after each transformation, while on the second one addElements is being called inside a callback, and is only called after all transformations have ocurred.